# Is there customer group in virtocommerce 2?

Tags: virtocommerce

I need to have a customer group  on the pricing module and some of the modules. 
Is there customer group in virtocommerce 2? If there is, where is the admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify customer group using tags, tags need to be added to customer object on storefront, also custom expressions can be easily created - https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/working-with-platform-manager/extending-functionality/composing-dynamic-conditions:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I realized how custom expressions can be added .but I do not understand how you can add tags to customer

Comment: **VirtoCommerce.Domain.Pricing.Model.PriceEvaluationContext** contains property **Tags**, values of this property used for checking pricing conditions  in"Tags contains" expression. On client code before sending request to prices evaluation, you can populate this Tags context property with values from any source. it can be Contact organization, or any dynamic property without any limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'm sorry that I do not understand well, because Recently I started to work with VirtoCommerce.I've worked with prestashop.
In the prestashop, there are groups of customers with the following values:(built in groups) "Visitor","Guest","Customer","Online marketing staff"  and another my custome group. in VirtoCommerce, for example in Promotion conditions , exist  (+ add user group) with built in groups : "everyone","First time buyer" and "Register user". i need these groups :"Guest","Online marketing staff", and my custom group for example Staff.

Comment: We are added support UserGroups today. Now you can assign UserGroups for contact and use this in promotions and prices assignment conditions. Please check this in our demo site: http://demo.virtocommerce.com/admin#/workspace/customers http://demo.virtocommerce.com/admin#/workspace/marketing